# Cannot register to GCM for push notifications on Android 5 and 5.1

Tags: android, actionscript-3, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an AIR application and I implemented push notifications for Android using GCM. The service works perfectly on all devices except those having Android 5.0 or 5.1 OS. The application simply doesn't receive a registration id from GCM.
Neither PERMISSION_GIVEN_WITH_TOKEN_EVENT nor PERMISSION_REFUSED_EVENT are never raised. I am not getting any response from GCM.
Did anybody have this problem? Could you please help me?

I am using Air Native Extension for Push Notifications from Freshplanet github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification

So this is my code:

```
    PushNotification.getInstance().registerForPushNotification(GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);                 PushNotification.getInstance().addEventListener(PushNotificationEvent.PERMISSION_REFUSED_EVENT, onPushNotificationTokenFailed); 
    function onPushNotificationToken(event:PushNotificationEvent):void { 
    trace("My push token is: " + event.token); 
}
    function onPushNotificationTokenFailed(event:PushNotificationEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.errorCode);
            trace(event.errorMessage);
            trace();
        }
```

And my manifest file (partial):

```
<permission android:name="MY_APP_ID.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"      android:protectionLevel="signature" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="MY_APP_ID.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<application> 
<activity android:name="com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.NotificationActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" /> 
<receiver android:name="com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
        <category android:name="MY_APP_ID" /> 
</intent-filter> 
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" /> 
        <category android:name="MY_APP_ID" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver> 
<service android:name="com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.LocalNotificationService"/> 
<receiver android:name="com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.LocalBroadcastReceiver" android:process=":remote">
</receiver>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to share your code what you did implemented :)

Comment: I am using Air Native Extension for Push Notifications from Freshplanet https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification
Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you share your android manifest file

Comment: edit your question instead of write the comments